# Wait for parent state to update before calling another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

## I'm calling a function that needs to do 2 things:

1. Call a parent-level function to update my database using a fetch request  and then update my parent-level state
2. Wait for 1st function to update my state, and then route to a view where my updated data is seen (using props)

The problem is I'm not sure how to wait for this 1st function to be complete before moving on to the 2nd. So when I try to change views with this 2nd function, the data shown isn't updated.

### The parent-level function that I would like to run and update my state.

```
updateEntry = (newHeader, newBody, index) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/update", {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        header: newHeader,
        body: newBody,
        index: index
    }),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { this.setState({journalDb: data })})
}
```

### The child level function where I call the parent level function using *updateEntry()*

```
initiateUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateEntry(value1, value2, value3)
    this.props.setEditMode();
}
```

The issue is my parent level state isn't updating in time to show when I change the route using *setEditMode()*... I'm not sure how to wait for the parent state to update before running this

Answer (score 0):

so what you could do is do something like this

```
updateEntry = (newHeader, newBody, index) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>fetch("http://localhost:3000/update", {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            header: newHeader,
            body: newBody,
            index: index
        }),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        this.setState({journalDb: data })
        resolve()
    })
})
```

and simply add

```
initiateUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateEntry(value1, value2, value3)
         .then(() => this.props.setEditMode());
}
```

this way you're guaranteed that updateEntry was finished when setEditMode is called

Comment: I think you could just return fetch as well, though I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `updateEntry` function to return the result of the fetch, as this is a promise. For example:

```
updateEntry = (newHeader, newBody, index) => fetch("http://localhost:3000/update", {
```

Then when you call the parent function, treat it just like a promise:

```
this.props.updateEntry(value1, value2, value3).then(() => {
  this.props.setEditMode()
})
```

Comment: This worked for the problem I described. Turns out it wasn't the issue I was having but I appreciate your answer. Thank you